# Mandar variables locales a Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo un ciclo `for` y dentro una llamada `ajax`. En el `success` utilizo una variable que se "procesa" con el ciclo y es diferente para cada llamada en el ajax. El problema esta en que el `success` no parece estar tomando los valores correspondiente para esta variable.

Ejemplo:

```
 for(var i = 0; i < longitud; i++) {
      $.ajax({
         url: url,
         data: data,
         type: 'POST',
         success: function(data) {
              if(data.status){
                   // En este punto i es undefined
                   $("#div"+i).html("Hi");
              }
         }
      });
 }
```

Comment: has un console.log() de data y fijate que te imprime en la consola del navegador

Comment: data no tiene problemas, la condición se cumple.El problema esta al tratar con el valor i, parace que en todas las llamadas siempre toma el último valor de i

Comment: No confundas success con done, me parece que lo que tu buscas es el done, es decir lo que traes de la url un poco más de [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847829/what-is-difference-between-success-and-done-method-of-ajax/8847912)

Comment: si sabes que un ajax dentro de un ciclo puede reventar con una conexion lenta?

Comment: pon tu codigo completo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amigo las peticiones **ajax** son asincrónicas lo que quiere decir que no sabes cuando dure en volver la respuesta.

Por eso el `for` si ejecuta las peticiones pero la variable `i` la obtiene al volver osea después de el tiempo que tomo en ir y hacer la petición así que `i` vale `10` porque el tiempo de el `for` es mucho mas rápido que el de cada petición dentro de el.

Espero te ayude saludos.

> **NOTA**: Se uso un API de prueba para hacer la consulta.

**Ejemplo**

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

$.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(i);
});

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Solucion

Si quieres puedes hacer una function re cursiva que solo se ejecuta al retornar el **ajax** seria como tu propio `for`

> La idea es ejecutar el ajax y que al retornar llame a la misma funcion pero con la variable de condición con un numero mas hasta que se cumpla y no se ejecute mas el Ajax.

**Ejemplo funcional**

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

 var numero = 0
 function miFor(numero){
  if(numero<10){
  $.ajax({
  url: root + '/posts/1',
  method: 'GET'
   }).then(function(data) {
   console.log(numero);
   numero++
   miFor(numero)
 });
  }
 }
 miFor(0)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Exactamente esto es lo que esta pasando. No abra una forma de adjuntar estos valores para luego usarlos en cualquier lugar del AJAX ?

Comment: puedes hacer el segundo ejemplo que puse para solucionarlo amigo

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: De nada amigo que bueno poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer que tus peticiones ajax sean sincronas. `jQuery.ajax()` tiene uno de sus parametros destinado a tal fin `async` que por defecto es `true`.

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    $.ajax({
        url: root + '/posts/' + i,
        method: 'GET',
        async:false
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```